Assertion functions on private members
Is there any way to add a type predicate definition for checkEvent so that I don't need the non-null-assertion operator for currentGigData in parseDate?
  private parseDate(text: string) {
    this.checkEvent("parseDate");

    const date = Number(text)
    if (!date) throw EmailParser.errors.couldntFindDate

    const { month, year } = this.currentDateMarker;
    this.currentGigData!.dateParts = {
      date, year, month
    }
  }

  private checkEvent(source: string) {
    if (this.currentGigData === null) {
      throw EmailParser.errors.noEventStarted(source);
    }
  }

Copilot suggested the following: but it has problems because it doesn't allow for the other members of the class. Also currentGigData itself had a problem:

The intersection this & { currentGigData: NonNullable<EmailParser['currentGigData']> } was reduced to never` because property currentGigData exists in multiple constituents and is private in some.

private checkEvent(source: string): this is { currentGigData: NonNullable<EmailParser['currentGigData']> } {
  if (this.currentGigData === null) {
    throw EmailParser.errors.noEventStarted(source);
  }
  return true;
}

It then suggested adding this is this & { currentGigData... which looked promising but didn't work, even if I changed it to this is typeof this & { ...
UPDATE
Thanks very much to @jsejcksn for suggesting using asserts, which I'd never seen before. I extracted the type of currentGigData into InProcessGigData so that currentGigData is declared as type InProcessGigData | null and then rewrote the signature for checkEvent:
private checkEvent(source: string): asserts this is this & { currentGigData: InProcessGigData }

However I still get the same error as above, because currentGigData is private. If I make it public everything works! This is tolerable in my app (side project) but I'd prefer to use more correct encapsulation (EmailParser has only one public method, static parse(html: string) and none of its innards should be public). The error is sensible so maybe it's impossible, but is there any way to achieve this? It seems a little silly that a signature within a class can't resolve private-ness of its own members (and you can't put private in the asserts clause.

Does this answer your question? What is the difference between "asserts value is type" and "value is type" in TypeScript?

Example of using an assertion function instead of a type guard: https://tsplay.dev/wE0BOW

Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing, instead of an excerpt of a larger code base that depends on private or third party declarations.  Right now if I look at this I get all kinds of errors you're not asking about, and it makes it difficult to get started.
